# the_content not working

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven

it doesn't display the content in editor i.e i have an image that i uploaded by using add media in the editor part which is not getting displayed plz help..it displays the thumbnail but not the content

i have the the code as follows :

```
 <?php if ( get_post_type() == bags ) { ?>

           <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

          <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

   <?php if ( get_post_type() == books ) { ?>

           <?php the_content('editor'); ?>
               <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>


          <?} ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

i m using it for posttypes where books is a postname

Comment: Could you please elaborate where is this happening? Are other template tags working? What is the Loop around it?

Comment: It has to be `'books'` not `books`. And what's the `endif;` for, when you are using `{...}`? And last but not least: What do you want with `'editor'`? This might not do what you expect it to. This is just the string for the read-more.

Comment: when i use the_post_thumnail(); instead of the_content(); i m able to display the featured image but the text or image inside the editor field is not displayed when i use the_content();

Comment: a few issues have already been pointed out above, I suggest [enabling debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), which will also reveal your errors.

Comment: i updated the code and clear problem after debugging plz recheck the code as the 2nd if is not checked at all

Comment: Please update your question with your current code. As @tf pointed out, you need to use `if( get_post_type() == 'books' )` -- `books` on its own is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Without wanting to be rude: You should start by reading some tutorials on PHP.

This is (most probably) what you want to do in your question:

```
<?php
if ('bags' == get_post_type())
    the_post_thumbnail();
elseif ('books' == get_post_type()) {
    the_content('editor');
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
?>
```

Is this working (as you want it to)?

Comment: doesn't work...but i modified the code further now in 2nd if the thumbnail gets displayed but not the content